# Continuous uniform distribution has infinite modes, the discrete one zero - Explanation

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

According to wikipedia, a [continuous uniform distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_uniform_distribution) has infinite modes:

[image]

instead for a [discrete uniform distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_uniform_distribution) the mode is not defined.

[image]

Why? Intuitively I would have said that also the discrete uniform distribution has multiple modes.

Comment: What's the definition of a "mode" of a distribution? When you say "has infinite modes" you mean "has infinitely many modes". right?

Comment: Hello @DavidC.Ullrich yes. I mean that there are infinite values of the random variable $X$ such that the pmf/pdf is maximum.

Comment: What is the "pmf"?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich probability mass function

Comment: Guessing what you mean by  "probability mass function" it seems that pmf/pdf=1, so _every_ point is a max of pmf/pdf

Comment: "there are infinite values of the random variable $X$ such that...: No, that's impossible! If $X$ is uniformly distributed on $(a,b)$ then $X$ does not have _any_ infinite values; the values are all finite.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich they are two different concepts: the pmf is used for the discrete random variables, the pdf for the continuous ones.

Comment: It is Wikipedia so different people write different things.  Clearly some  discrete distributions can have modes (for example the Poisson distribution has one, or two adjacent if the parameter is an integer), but it depends on your definition.  I would be happy to say that any value in the support of a uniform equally-spaced discrete distribution can be regarded as  a  mode, and did so in http://www.se16.info/hgb/mode.pdf

Comment: @Henry "Clearly discrete distributions can have modes " what's the _definition_ of "mode"?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Intuitively the mode is the most likely value.  Definitions can then be used to make this more precise in particular cases.  For example, I said in that link that an equally spaced probability mass function for a discrete random variable $D$ is *unimodal with mode* $\hat D$ if the probability mass function is weakly increasing up to $\hat D$ and weakly decreasing from $\hat D$ onwards. Then *equally spaced* needs definition, but that is not too difficult.  And note that my definition of unimodal does not exclude the possibility of more than one mode

Comment: @Henry thank you for your contribution.

Comment: @Henry "Most likely value" is what I would have thought, except I can't make any sense of that for a continuous distribution.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I said *most likely* rather than *most probable* to try to deal with that.  If there is a well-behaved density for a continuous distribution, the mode is typically taken to be the point(s) of highest density, with more careful definition when this does not work (slightly circular as well-behaved means a case where this works). I once managed to convince someone that the mode of the square-root of a Cantor-distributed random variable must be at $1$ even though this is a distribution without a density or any points of positive probability